# 2-Factor Auth with SSH

Tags: authentication, ssh

I recently acquired a Synology NAS (DS1513+).

I am looking to expose SSH access remotely and to that end would like to harden SSH as much as possible. Is 2 Factor auth possible and if so what are the options that exist.

Please note, I am aware of the PAM-based Google Auth module but wanted to know if there are alternative approaches.

Comment: What's wrong with PAM-based 2FA? Anyway, instead of PAM-based 2FA, you can use the `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config` to introduce your own 2FA script after password authentication. It can be as simple as sending a random string to the user's email (or phone number as SMS) and then checking for it before spawning a shell.

Comment: @Adnan I think the question was worded awkwardly. I more wanted to know what other alternatives there were in general to Google Authenticator, be they PAM-based or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a PAM module for just about everything. You pick your auth token, there's a PAM module for it. [SecurID](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-authentication-agents/pam-7-1.htm), [Yubikey](https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-pam), [Text Message](http://smsid.sourceforge.net/), you name it. And yes, also [TOTP](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/) (e.g. [Google Authenticator](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en), [Microsoft Authenticator](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/authenticator/e7994dbc-2336-4950-91ba-ca22d653759b), etc)

If you're looking for doing authentication somewhere *other* than PAM, then perhaps you should re-evaluate your goals. They call it Pluggable Authentication Modules for a reason. That's exactly where authentication should happen.

Comment: Out of curiosity for the TOTP options you mention, are they reliant on connectivity with Google, for instance. For instance, if I wanted to have TOTP just on my internal network with no WAN connectivity, is that doable or are Google/MS involved at some point during the initial setup process (ie. generating the 2D barcode, etc)?

Comment: @speedRS No. Go read the spec.

Comment: @speedRS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm

Comment: The google-authenticator PAM module works fine with OpenSSH, it's self-contained (no Google servers involved). If you're using it with a TOTP token though, note it has a hard-coded timestep of 30s which may need to be modified (some use 60s).